# pip install is giving ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I am using miniconda version of python and I've create virtual environment using virtualenv command.
Initially pip install command was working fine but after sometime it started giving me ModuleNotFoundError

when I called the command to install jupyter notebook.

```
pip install jupyter
```

and I also tried

```
pip3 install jupyter
```

even `pip list` command is not working.

error which I got was

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/aarsh/Code/p/bin/pip", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Users/aarsh/Code/p/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 73, in main
    command = create_command(cmd_name, isolated=("--isolated" in cmd_args))
  File "/Users/aarsh/Code/p/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/__init__.py", line 104, in create_command
    module = importlib.import_module(module_path)
  File "/Users/aarsh/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/aarsh/Code/p/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 17, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.req_command import RequirementCommand, with_cleanup
  File "/Users/aarsh/Code/p/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 19, in <module>
    from pip._internal.network.download import Downloader
  File "/Users/aarsh/Code/p/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/network/download.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pip._internal.network.cache import is_from_cache
  File "/Users/aarsh/Code/p/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/network/cache.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.cachecontrol.cache import BaseCache
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._vendor.cachecontrol'
```

Please Help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Did you try `conda install jupyter` ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the same problem mentioned in [pip and pip3 no longer work](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=263782)

The solution was to reinstall and upgrade pip

```
ls .local/lib/python3.5/sitepackages
pip dist-packages
ls  .local/lib/python2.7/sitepackages
pip dist-packages
```

Then

```
sudo pip3 install --force-reinstall --upgrade pip
sudo pip install --force-reinstall --upgrade pip
```

The mentioned command are for linux-based, you might need different cmd for windows

Answer (score -2):

Try: `pip install notebook` or `pip3 install notebook`
If you dont have pip, try: `conda install notebook`

Answer (score -3):

try this:
`pip install jupyterlab`
try `pip3` if `pip` doesn't work:
`pip3 install jupyterlab`

Comment: Output is same even for pip install jupyterlab